# Close a div and start a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a list of items that I want to be inside multiple columns. These columns can be arbitrary based on a series of factors so there's some other stuff going on. Unfortunately I'm getting tricked up on how to close the containing div.

Let's say I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 JS-columnGrid">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
<!--</div>-->
<!--<div class="col-md-4">-->
    <li>four</li>    
</div>
```

I want to close the col-md-4 div after the third list element, and wrap the fourth list element in another div class="col-md-4">

This would create two columns.

Here's some javascript that would grab each list, throw it into an array and then my intention is that I can use that array to decide where I'm going to cut the column.

```
   var cutoffArray = [];
    $(".JS-columnGrid > li").each(function(){
        cutoffArray.push(this);
        console.log(cutoffArray);
    });

    $(cutoffArray[3]).before("</div><div class='col-md-3'>");
```

Unfortunately this is the output HTML after this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 JS-columnGrid">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <li>four</li>    
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) is not valid content directly in a `div`.

Comment: I think you'll have to add another div after the first one, and move the elements inside the new div.

Comment: Yes hes right. <li> needs to be within <nav> <ul> <ol> to name a few

Comment: I think that should be `<ul>`, `<ol>` and `<menu>` (only implemented in FF) tags **only**.

Comment: @phtrivier Is correct. You can't split a div. Create a new one and move the items over.

Answer (score 2):

```
// select and remove all the elements you want to re-package
var $lis = $(".col-md-4.JS-columnGrid li").remove(), 
    i,
    divs = [];

$(".outer-container").empty();

// slice into packs of three and append each pack to container
for (i = 0; i < $lis.length; i += 3) {
    $("<div class='col-md-3'></div>")
        .append( $lis.slice(i, i + 3) )
        .appendTo(".outer-container");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){

    var cutoffArray = [],
        $col = $('<div class="col-md-3"></div>');

    $(".JS-columnGrid > li").each(function(){
        cutoffArray.push(this);
    });

    $('.JS-columnGrid').after($col);
    $(cutoffArray[3]).appendTo($col);

});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bj9w36r9/1/)

Updated answer:

if you want to add more li's change the above to this:

```
var $col = $('<div class="col-md-3"></div>');

$('.JS-columnGrid').after($col);
$(".JS-columnGrid > li").each(function(index){
    if(index > 2) {
         $col.append($(this));   
    }
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bj9w36r9/2/)

Comment: What happens when you add another li item after 4. It is within the first column.

Answer (score 0):

despite the fact that you have `<li>` elements in the "wrong" place, browsers wont just ignore them and you can still manipulate them

```
var div = document.querySelector('.col-md-4.JS-columnGrid');
var lis = div.querySelectorAll('li');
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.className = 'col-md-3';
for (var i = 3; i < lis.length; i++) {
    newDiv.appendChild(lis[i]);
}
div.parentElement.insertBefore(newDiv, div.nextElementSibling);
```

That will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `"</div><div>"` in `.before()` etc, since the argument is expected to be one or more properly formatted HTML elements (or plain text). You're working on the DOM here, not plain text, and the textual HTML representation of the argument is purely convenience.

You could instead simply **move** the elements:

```
    var els = $('.JS-columnGrid > li');
    var x = $( "<div class='col-md-4 JS-columnGrid'></div>" );
    els.parent().after( x );

    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i ++ )
      if ( i >= 3 )
        x.append( els[i] );
```